# full screen div when displayed to take default window scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an issue with a full screen div; it's a toggle, when this div displays it takes up the full screen of the browser window.

The problem is, is the browser window scroll bar when scrolled or used, it does not navigate within the full screen div *(in which is longer vertical)* so it remains useless and an ugly user experience. *It seems to still be scrolling through full page content from the site in the background of full screen div.*

I was able to display and nest an additional scrollbar with this shown div *(using the overflow property but this is not what I want)*, and that works but then you have two scroll bars and it's even uglier. **Is there anyway to have my div, when shown / displayed, to take / allow use of default browser window scrollbar? So that when it is displayed, the user can use the default scroll bar to navigate down and upward.**

*Maybe the solution is using overflow scroll within the full screen div when it is show and then hiding the default regular browser window scroll bar?*

Comment: What if you put your html, body { width : 100%, height : 100%; overflow : hidden } and had a scrollbar on your div "replace" the scrollbar of your body with { overflow : scroll } ? Otherwise it's javascript I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class for the body. Don't use it by default.

```
.showTheDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Give the div a class:

```
<div class="divToShow">
```

Define that class as:

```
.divToShow {
    display: none;
}

.showTheDiv .divToShow {
    display: block;
}
```

To display the div use:

```
$('body').toggleClass('showTheDiv'):
```

Hope this works.